# Need a simple GUI in AutoHotkey script

Tags: autohotkey, gui

I am very new to programming and I have a very simple code that I made for a game to not let me go afk (yes, I know there are easier ways). If anyone would be kind enough I would like a VERY simple GUI with a button that when you press it it starts my code. Here it is:

```
Persistent
SetTimer, PressTheKey, 10000
Return

PressTheKey:
Send, {H}
Sleep 10
Send, {e}
Sleep 10
Send, {l}
Sleep 10
Send, {l}
Sleep 10
Send, {o}
Sleep 10
Send, {Enter}

Return

Esc::ExitApp
```

Comment: It might be easier to have a hotkey to start and stop your afk script.

Answer (score 1):

- Step 1: Download [SciTE4AutoHotkey](http://fincs.ahk4.net/scite4ahk/)
- Step 2: Install and Run
- Step 3: Start the SmartGUI creator using the toolbar icon or Ctrl+1
- Step 4: Make a button on your new GUI
- Step 5: Save Script and Exit (select option to Insert New GUI into to SciTE)
- Step 6: Where the window coordinates are now listed (`x52 y90 w100 h20, Button`), insert the name of your subroutine with 'g' in front of it (`x52 y90 w100 h20 gPressTheKey, Button`)
- Step 7: Execute the GUI that YOU wrote!!

Comment: Gui, Add, Text, x32 y269 w100 h70 gPressTheKey, Run Toontown Script
Gui, Add, Text, x42 y-41 w80 h10 , Text
Gui, Add, GroupBox, x82 y-51 w340 h420 , GroupBox
Gui, Add, Picture, x2 y-1 w470 h200 , C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\sweet.jpg
Gui, Add, Edit, x632 y269 w-410 h-230 , Edit
Gui, Add, MonthCal, x212 y209 w250 h150 , 
Gui, Show, w479 h379, Koog's Toontown Script
return


#Persistent
SetTimer, PressTheKey, 10000
Return

PressTheKey:
Send, {H}
Sleep 10
Send, {e}
Sleep 10
Send, {l}
Sleep 10
Send, {l}
Sleep 10
Send, {o}
Sleep 10
Send, {Enter}

Return

Esc::ExitApp

Comment: That is my code so far but it wont work for some reason

Comment: On line 1 it says its not working

Comment: See if using 'Button' for your button name works (i.e., start off simple as suggested, and don't add spaces to the button name until you get it to work right)